# Playing, Opening and Pausing VLC command line executed from Python scripts

Tags: python, ipc, vlc

I am trying to create an small python app that syncs up 2 computers via tcp socket and when I send a command play or pause. Both scripts will/should execute a command line to pause or play or open vlc wit file.  Both computers are MacOSX latest with a VLC installed within the past 3 weeks.

I have been reading the documentation using `.../vlc -H` for the long help but I still don't seem to `--global-key-play-pauses` or plays. I got it to open a video but I wasn't able to send any commands while it's running.

I tried some examples I saw online with no avail. I have the 2 scripts ready just not the VLC commands.

```
c-mbp:~ c$ /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -I --global-key-play-pauses
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-3-gf8c9253)
[0000000100604a58] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[000000010050d928] core libvlc error: interface "default" initialization failed
```

Comment: Maybe you have to enable a cli interface before you can use those commands?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the best way to do this on MacOS would be to use the [VLC remote control interface](https://wiki.videolan.org/documentation:modules/rc/).

This allows you to control the behavior of a launched VLC instance using commands which you send to the process' stdin.

You could then use the Python [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to launch VLC and then send the appropriate commands to the stdin of this process.

If you were using Linux this could likely be more simply achieved through the VLC DBUS interface however the remote control through stdin should still give you sufficient control for what you are doing.

Comment: I am still having problems, do you have an example?

Answer (score 2):

First install python-vlc

```
python3 -m pip install python-vlc
```

Then Create a very Basic python script

```
import vlc

# Create Player Object and set MRL (your_video.mp4)
player = vlc.MediaPlayer('your_video.mp4')

# Basic Commands associated with the class object
player.play()
player.pause()
player.stop()
```

Further info:

[VLC Python Bindings](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings)

[API Documentation](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/)

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer. Posts of entirely code are frowned upon.

Comment: Any answer that says "install more software" is generally a bad one.